# How to get Debug output from unit tests in TFS 2015

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, visual-studio-2015, continuous-integration, tfs-2015

When running unit tests locally in Visual Studio 2015, I can click on the Output hyperlink in the test results and gain access to all the Debug Trace output (as Standard Output) on the test output page.

[image]

[image: Sample Test Output]

However when using a build agent to build and test, I can't find any way to gain access to this output information. I've dug through every screen I can think of and nothing. All it shows is the Assert exception message and the stack trace.

[image]

Even if I download the .trx file it doesn't include the Console Output section.

[image]

Is there any way to get this output from a test run performed by an agent?

Also, some of my tests write additional information to the TestResults folder. The contents of this folder also appears to be excluded from the stored test information. Is there any way to get that as well?

The only other thing I can think of would be to have my tests write all their debug information to files then copy those to another folder as a build step. Seems kind of kludgy. If I remember correctly, the "old" TFS build process would save all this information automatically and it was available looking at test runs in Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you created a variable in the build definition called system.debug and set it to true?

Comment: Did the  "Debug trace“  info automatically generated by VS2015 or you write those info in the Console Output section?

Comment: Apparently system.debug was set to false. I changed it and am running the build again to see if I get the desired results. (it takes a while to run)

Comment: Setting the system.debug flag didn't seem to change anything. I still get just an exception message and a stack trace. Patrick-MSFT, in VS2015 the Debug.WriteLine info does automatically show up in the test result's Output link. I didn't do anything to enable it. It was just there by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine()` instead of `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()`, you will get the information when run the test from TFS:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah, you hit it! After reading your answer I went back and looked at a build that outputs Debug instead of Release and the console output shows up for those. That reminded me that the Debug.Xxx methods are NOP'd in Release builds. Switching to Trace did the trick. Thanks!